# How do I Automate Google/Facebook SignUp in iOS using XCUITesting?

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

How do I get new Google and Facebook accounts for every SignUp ? If I use the same Facebook or Google Account then My app throws "Account already exists". Is there any website which has dummy facebook or Google accounts for testing purposes ?

Comment: In Facebook Developer tools you can create test users.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issues and log out the app before launching for testing, and then we will add random emails.    Create a random email address for each test execution

```
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    let email = "stack" + uuid + "@example.com"

    an email will be stack3r33045454-4343@example.com
```

FYI example.com is created for testing purpose other domain may get unwanted emails from facebook.com

example.com: This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

Comment: I need to make use of "SignUp with Google" Button every-time.